# No authenticationScheme was specified error even when JWT Authentication Specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory

I'm new to AzureAD authentication. I setup my Web API with below settings in startup.cs

```
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedopt => sharedopt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer("AzureAd", options =>
        {
            options.Audience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Audience");
            options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Instance")
            + Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId");
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Issuer"),
                ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Audience")
            };

        });
```

I am expecting my Client App (Angular) will attach Authorization header in its requests and thus it will get access to API

But when I execute the Web API and trying to open any API with Authorize, it triggers this error

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
> there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be
> set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
> AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

I already specified JWTBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme. Still why its not accepting?

Answer (score 9):

Please remove the first "AzureAd" parameter from AddJwtBearer call.

TLDR: When you call AddAuthentication you set the default scheme to `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` which is string "Bearer".

This tells the authentication middleware to authenticate all requests (unless specified otherwise e.g. via Authorize attribute with schemes) to use a set of handlers and configurations organized by the shceme name "Bearer".
However you didn't register that scheme. Your call to `AddJwtBearer` registers a scheme named "AzureAd" instead of "Bearer".

Authentication middleware cannot find the matching scheme and hence the error.

If you don't specify the "AzureAd" parameter, below version of `AddJwtBearer` is invoked:

```
  builder.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, configureOptions);
```

As we can see, it registers the JwtBearer authentication with scheme "Bearer" matching your default scheme.

Comment: I had the same exact problem and this solved it for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You might have missed to register
**services.ConfigureApiAuthentication(Configuration);** in the startup class

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you don't have an **[Authorize]** attribute above your Controller class definition or any associated methods for which you don't want any Authentication. I copy/pasted a Controller class and didn't notice it had an **[Authorize]** attribute above the class definition. I removed that and the problem was resolved.